# return height from getHeight() out of screen

Tags: android

```
  canvas.drawLine(10, 10, 10, canvas.getHeight(), paint);   
  canvas.drawLine(0, canvas.getHeight(), 100, canvas.getHeight(), paint);
//the vertical line can see, but the level line disappear,at first I thought it's because the length ,so I minus 30 on length,but it's the same

  canvas.drawLine(0, canvas.getHeight()-30, 100, canvas.getHeight()-30, paint);
```

I'm going to put an image in it, but it out of the screen range. The view is inherit and overwrite `onDraw` method. I have tried set the default background, and the height is out of screen too.

Could anyone help me?

[image: the picture now I get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial target density for default Canvas Constructor is [DENSITY_NONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#DENSITY_NONE) so the layer size is set to 0 - 0. You must setDesity for canvas, or getHeight of screen from [Display](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html), or this View.getHeight. In this way I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you even didn't checked what canvas.getHeight() returns. Please check it and you will know why the line is not visible.
Please also notice that canvas size may be larger than view. You should use View.getHeight()